# Небольшая ошибка в справке по расширенным спискам + (возможно) проблемы с отображением блока оглавления

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице справки по расширенным спискам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) есть текст

> ```
> 2.  Несколько пунктов внутри списка:
>         Лучше всего отделять абзацы четырьмя пробелами
>         Можно оставлять и три, но это может 
>         проблемы при вложении других объектов
>         Оставьте четыре.
> ```

Кажется между выделенными строчками пропущено слово «вызвать».

---

Плюс блок оглавления возможно ведёт себя как-то не так (перекрывает поднятый наверх блок справки для расширенных списков и неплавно изменяет положение при первой прокрутки вниз)

Answer (score 2):

Добавил в перевод пропущенное слово «вызвать». Ждите дальнейших действий ответственных лиц.

По поводу перекрытия, есть баг на MSE: [Contents block overlaps document body in help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303321/339911)